# Term for number of crossings of smooth curves

Tags: co.combinatorics, gn.general-topology

Two smooth oriented finite curves $g_1, g_2$ on e.g. the 2-dimensional torus can intersect each other transversally in two ways: either the pair $(Tg_1(x),Tg_2(x))$ of tangent vectors in the intersection point $x$ is a positively oriented, or a negatively oriented basis. $n(x)=1$ if the former is the case and $n(x)=-1$ otherwise.

Is there a name for the integer obtained when we take the sum of $n(x)$ over all intersection points $x$?

Comment: It's usually called the *algebraic intersection* of the two curves.

Comment: @Tony has given the answer, but I want to know what "finite curves" are...

Answer (score 1):

To remove this question from the "unanswered" queue: As Tony Huynh said in a comment, the sum of $n(x)$ is called the *algebraic intersection* of the curves.